# Codeigniter routes not working, only default controller is working?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am working in code igniter and getting url rewriting issue. Default controller is working and other controllers showing 404 error.  It's not even going to controller function. This is my routes file.

```
$route['404_override']                          = 'my404';
$route['default_controller']                    = 'welcome';
$route['translate_uri_dashes']                  = FALSE;

$route['admin/login']                           = 'admin/login/login';
$route['admin/login-check']                     = 'admin/login/login_check';
```

my login controller is in admin directory in controllers. so path is controllers/admin/Login.php. I tried to check with die() at the top but it's not even going into controller file. This is my htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

Main point is that it's working fine on localhost but on server it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Check your method name in **ManageUser.php** . Seems like it does not match with the route.

Try updating following route:

```
$route['admin/add-new-user'] = 'admin/manageuser/add_new_user';
```

With this:

```
$route['admin/add-new-user'] = 'admin/manageuser/add_user';
```

Comment: it's matching but no controller is working only welcome(default) controller is working

Comment: which server do you using Apache2 or Nginx? if its Nginx then .htaccess will not work.

Comment: i am using nginx. can you please let me know why this issue is coming on nginx server and how we can solve it